# Запуск графических приложений на сервере Linux

Tags: linux, сервер, vps, rdp, xorg

Есть слабенький VPS сервер Linux.
Мне нужно добиться работы графического приложения на этом сервере, а именно, браузера frefox, который будет отображать сайт и который будет работать без активной сессии-подключения к серверу, то есть удаленно. Также чтобы была возможность подключиться к виртуальному рабочему столу визуально, и 'подвигать' окно работающего браузера на сервере. Сервак голый, без графической оболочки и прочих пакетов. Подскажите пожалуйста хронологию установки\настройки малотребовательных к ресурсам пакетов, необходимых для работы вышеописанной элементарной задачи.

Comment: 1. установить vnc-сервер. 2. конец программы.

Comment: можно ещё настроить его на 16 цветов и маленький размер экрана для экономии памяти

Comment: Даже если ты это сделаешь - этим будет крайне неприятно пользоваться. Можно узнать - нафига такие костыли?

Comment: @donRumata, по простой причине что не имею рабочего компьютера, который должен работать нон-стоп. юзаю ноут и живу на чемоданах. в связи с чем и начал изучать nix администрирование серверов

Comment: @Михаил, конкретно гуй\браузер зачем?

Comment: @donRumata, для работы скрипту на питоне необходима постоянная работа браузера и доступ в сеть, что-то типо парсера

Comment: @Михаил, если скрипт парсит html - может проще дёргать страницы через wget\curl\aria2c\elinks?

Comment: @Михаил Надо было про скрипт на питоне и писать в вопросе. Попробуйте `webdriver.PhantomJS()` для headless-режима парсинга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

две разных задачи:

1) headless броузер - это phantom и компания

2) подвигать окно "ssh -X" и вперед

Comment: а можно про первый поподробнее? PhantomJS я так полагаю, а что за компания?

Comment: "use the google luke". phantomjs - это headless browser, приложение такое, оно решает первую часть вопроса.

Comment: @Михаил, "good news, everyone".  В Chrome появилась возможность работы без графического вывода: https://www.linux.org.ru/news/internet/13352950